# Using placement new with an std::function doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019, std-function, placement-new

This code crashes at `(*function)()`. I'm running Visual Studio 2019 and compiling C++17 for Windows 10 x86_64. I've tested it on Linux with GCC (-std=c++17) and it works fine. I'm wondering if this is a problem with Visual Studio's C++ compiler or something that I'm not seeing.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const size_t blockSize = sizeof(std::function<void()>);
  using block = std::array<char, blockSize>;
  std::vector<block> blocks;

  auto lambda = [](){
    std::cout << "The lambda was successfully called.\n";
  };

  blocks.emplace_back(); 
  new (&blocks[0]) std::function<void()>(lambda);

  blocks.emplace_back(); 
  new (&blocks[1]) std::function<void()>(lambda);

  std::function<void()> *function = (std::function<void()> *)blocks[0].data();

  (*function)();

  return 0;
}
```

The error is a read access violation in the std::function internals.

Comment: Does that still happen if you remove the second `emplace_back`?

Comment: The answer by MilesBudnek explains the most serious issue. But it would also be safer to use `std::aligned_storage` instead of `std::array`, and to use `std::launder` on the result of the pointer cast.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo If I removed the second `emplace_back`, the placement at `&blocks[1]` would be in unallocated memory. But if I remove both statements, the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: This is a problem that's best solved by unasking the question. Don't do that. <g>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you append an element to a `std::vector` and that element would make the vector's size greater than its capacity the vector has to allocate new storage and copy/move all of its elements to the new space.  While you've constructed complex `std::function` objects in the `char` arrays held in your vector, the vector doesn't know that.  The underlying bytes that make up the `std::function` object will get copied to the vector's new storage, but the `std::function`'s copy/move constructor won't get called.

The best solution would be to just use a `std::vector<std::function<void()>>` directly.  If you *have* to use a vector of blocks of raw storage for some reason then you'll need to pre-allocate space before you start inserting elements.  i.e.

```
int main() {
  const size_t blockSize = sizeof(std::function<void()>);
  using block = std::array<char, blockSize>;
  std::vector<block> blocks;

  auto lambda = [](){
    std::cout << "The lambda was successfully called.\n";
  };

  blocks.reserve(2);  // pre-allocate space for 2 blocks

  blocks.emplace_back(); 
  new (&blocks[0]) std::function<void()>(lambda);

  blocks.emplace_back(); 
  new (&blocks[1]) std::function<void()>(lambda);

  std::function<void()> *function = (std::function<void()> *)blocks[0].data();

  (*function)();

  return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db5bfccf16e859cb)

Alternatively you could use a different data structure such as `std::list` that maintains stable addresses when elements are added or removed.